# SEARCH (not UID SEARCH) with mailkit

Tags: mailkit

Is it possible to use SEARCH imap command (not UID SEARCH) using mailkit?

I need it because of that

```
  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-72
  An EXPUNGE response MUST NOT be sent when no command is in
  progress, nor while responding to a FETCH, STORE, or SEARCH
  command.  This rule is necessary to prevent a loss of
  synchronization of message sequence numbers between client and
  server. 

       Note: UID FETCH, UID STORE, and UID SEARCH are different
       commands from FETCH, STORE, and SEARCH.  An EXPUNGE
       response MAY be sent during a UID command.
```

you won't get EXPUNGE or EXISTS using SEARCH(not UID SEARCH) which is important when I am getting my local indices in sync with the server. By looking at the code all search methods generate UID SEARCH. Is there a way to using just SEARCH?

UPDATE:

I'll try to explain the problem. In order to handle correctly EXPUNGE or EXISTS local index need to be in sync with the remote index (since those commands work with indices not with UIDs). So the first thing you need to do when open a folder is usually to bring local index up to date with the remote index. After that it is safe to execute EXPUNGE or EXISTS untagged response. That is why during the operation where remote and local index are synchronizing it is critical not to receive EXPUNGE or EXISTS, because I can't handle them correctly at that time (because my local index won't match the remote). I believe that is the reason why FETCH and SEARCH are implemented that way  (not emit untagged  EXPUNGE or EXISTS) to allow you to do that. Once I got local and remote index up to date it really doesn't matter if you use UID SEARCH or SEARCH.

Comment: I don't understand why you need SEARCH instead of UID SEARCH. UID SEARCH doesn't need indices because it uses UIDs, so your usage case makes no sense.

Comment: Hey Jeffrey, see my update in the original post.

Comment: You aren't synchronizing your folders correctly if you think you need the non-UID variant of SEARCH in order to do it right. You can use UID FETCH, for one. Secondly, your SEARCH results are useless if indexes change before you can use the results.

Comment: Show me your steps that you are using to try and synchronize your local index and I will show you a better way to do it.